# Django + Celery:Running celery with daemonized workers on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There has been some discussion on the web about this (SO, AWS Forums, blog posts) about how to daemonize and run Celery workers for Django applications on Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances. From what I understand, the summary of the above discussion gives two options-

1. Create a custom AMI with scripts to run Celery and use those AMIs to start celery in daemon mode.
2. Write some scripts in the .config file to customize the container which creates an init file on the EC2 instance, and then start celery with the `manage.py celeryd` command.

However, both of the above methods seem very messy and an overkill for something that otherwise can be done very simply on a standalone EC2 instance. I was able to run celery on a standalone EC2 instance using `celeryd` init scripts- http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html - which was similar to step 2 above (creating some files on the server) and then running `manage.py celeryd` command

Does anyone know of a simpler tried and tested way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by messy and overkill? Creating one EC2 instance, setting up everything to make celery work with one main broker and then replicating it using AMI based on your first manually configured instance is too much?

Comment: @daniula I thought using the AMI was a bit of an overkill because say if I wanted to add some other config tomorrow or change something in the Celery config file, in that case I would have to create a new AMI on top of this AMI. So now I have to version control my AMIs too along with the code.

Comment: If you think your configs will change often, configure your instances to pull it from one source at startup and every couple minutes.

Comment: So for creating the custom AMI to support Celery, would you recommend using `supervisorctl` method as described here, or one of the other methods? http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#supervisord

Comment: Yes, supervisorctl is quite popular to run wsgi with django app and celery next to it.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems it is easier when the webserver and celery workers are in different instances. However, I want to run them in the same instance (no need to pay for another EC2 instance currently). But beanstalk already configures its own supervisord when starting the EC2 instance, and I am not sure how to plug into it. Any info you might provide will be very helpful.